# PHP Encoding JSON As Individual Arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I believe I may have a syntax problem with a PHP page I am working on, but despite testing multiple ways, I can't seem to crack this.

For context, I have a page that queries a MySQL database and gets a set of department names and the hostname of three servers (a Mac, Windows, and Linux) of each department.  Once it has this data, it calls a function that uses these hostnames to get more specific sets of data about each server (lets say through other MySQL queries, CURLs, etc.) and adds the data for each department's servers to an array.  Ideally, I am trying to print the arrays as JSON data, but have all the JSON data be a part of one master array.  Everything is working, except the JSON data is separating each array into its own entity;

```
{
"department": "Math",
"macOS": "10.10.3",
"macRAM": "64GB",
"windowsOS": "2012.2",
"windowsRAM": "128GB",
"linuxOS": "5.5.1",
"linuxRAM": "32GB",
}
{
"department": "Science",
"macOS": "10.9.5",
"macRAM": "64GB",
"windowsOS": "XP",
"windowsRAM": "128GB",
"linuxOS": "1.2.3",
"linuxRAM": "32GB",
}
```

As noted above, the JSON data being presented is not separated by commas are embedded in brackets.  I'm hoping for;

```
[
{
"department": "Math",
"macOS": "10.10.3",
"macRAM": "64GB",
"windowsOS": "2012.2",
"windowsRAM": "128GB",
"linuxOS": "5.5.1",
"linuxRAM": "32GB",
},
{
"department": "Science",
"macOS": "10.9.5",
"macRAM": "64GB",
"windowsOS": "XP",
"windowsRAM": "128GB",
"linuxOS": "1.2.3",
"linuxRAM": "32GB",
}
]
```

Sorry for the length, but here is my PHP that is doing all the work;

```
<?php
$data = array();
?>

<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die('Error connecting to MySQLserver.');
mysqli_select_db($conn, "Database") or die("Failed to connect to database");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Servers";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $department = $row['department'];
    $serverMac = $row['serverMac'];
    $serverWindows = $row['serverWindows'];
    $serverLinux = $row['serverLinux'];
    getData($department, $serverMac, $serverWindows, $serverLinux);
}
} else {
echo "Unable to connection to server.  Please check your settings.";
}
?>

<?
function getData($serverMac, $serverWindows, $serverLinux) {

//Gather Data About Server Mac
//do something with the variable $serverMac

//Gather Data About Server Windows
//do something with the variable $serverWindows

//Gather Data About Server Linux
//do something with the variable $serverLinux

//Put The Gathered Data In An Array
$data = array('department' => $department, 
'macOS' => $macOS, 
'macRAM' => $macRAM
'windowsOS' => $windowsOS,
'windowsRAM' => $windowsRAM,
'linuxOS' => $linuxOS,
'linuxRAM' => $linuxRAM);
printData($data);
}
?>

<?php
function printData($data) {
echo "<pre>";
echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo "</pre>";
}
?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to store all data about servers in a nested php array. `json_encode` will then take care of the rest.

```
<?php
$data = array();

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die('Error connecting to MySQLserver.');
mysqli_select_db($conn, "Database") or die("Failed to connect to database");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Servers";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$servers = array();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $department = $row['department'];
        $serverMac = $row['serverMac'];
        $serverWindows = $row['serverWindows'];
        $serverLinux = $row['serverLinux'];
        $servers[] = getData($department, $serverMac, $serverWindows, $serverLinux);
    }

    printData($servers);

} else {
    echo "Unable to connection to server.  Please check your settings.";
}

function getData($serverMac, $serverWindows, $serverLinux) {

    //Gather Data About Server Mac
    //do something with the variable $serverMac

    //Gather Data About Server Windows
    //do something with the variable $serverWindows

    //Gather Data About Server Linux
    //do something with the variable $serverLinux

    //Put The Gathered Data In An Array
    $data = array(
        'department' => $department, 
        'macOS' => $macOS, 
        'macRAM' => $macRAM
        'windowsOS' => $windowsOS,
        'windowsRAM' => $windowsRAM,
        'linuxOS' => $linuxOS,
        'linuxRAM' => $linuxRAM);

    return $data;
}

function printData($data) {
    echo "<pre>";
    echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    echo "</pre>";
}
?>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly!  Thank you SO much!  This was incredibly helpful!

Comment: Just be aware that the `<pre>` tag in the output are hidden in your browser, but they still are in the source code and will destroy the result for any client expecting pure JSON.